# Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add records into two tables below,

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(Custno     CHAR(3),
 Custname   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 Custstreet VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Custcity   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 Custprov   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 Custpcode  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 Disc       DECIMAL(3,1),
 Balance    DECIMAL(7,2),
 Credlimit  DECIMAL(5),
 Srepno     CHAR(3),
 CONSTRAINT pkcustno PRIMARY KEY (Custno),
 CONSTRAINT fksrepno FOREIGN KEY (Srepno) REFERENCES salesrep(Srepno)
);


CREATE TABLE orders
(Orderno   CHAR(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Orderdate DATE,
 Custno    CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fkordercust FOREIGN KEY (Custno) REFERENCES customer (Custno)
);
```

When adding like this,

```
INSERT INTO orders(Orderno, Orderdate, Custno) VALUES('14587','2011-11-09', '125' );
INSERT INTO orders(Orderno, Orderdate, Custno) VALUES('11547','2011-11-07', '125' );
```

I get, "**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sh`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `fkordercust` FOREIGN KEY (`Custno`) REFERENCES `customer` (`Custno`))**
"
Is something wrong the table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not have a customer with `CustNo = '125'`.  Because of this, the `Foreign key` fails. You are trying to place an order for a non-existent customer, the DB throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

Do you actually *have* a customer row for customer number 125? I think not. The error message is telling you *exactly* what's wrong.

The foreign key constraint which ensures that no orders can be created for non-existent customers is being violated:

```
CONSTRAINT fkordercust FOREIGN KEY (Custno) REFERENCES customer (Custno)
```

Create the customer row *first* then you can add order rows for that customer to your heart's content.

Answer (score 3):

Your table is fine, you just don't have a customer with a CustNo of '125' in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You have created a foreign key to the customer table, but ( apparently ) inserted no data into it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a customer with a number of 125?